# Hamster refuses to climb back up pipe

Tags: psychology, hamsters

My Hamster that I got yesterday went down a curvy tube into another part of her cage (a separate container) and acted like she wanted out, but when she climbed back up the tube she got to a point and just stopped. Then she came back down and resumed trying to get out. Any idea why she stopped?

Comment: Has he been able to get out of the area on his own yet?

Comment: @RebeccaRVT What do you mean? Escaped? I only got her a few days ago

Comment: As in has he crawled through the pipe to get to the other side?

Comment: @RebeccaRVT Yes. Just she won't come back up the pipe. Or she wouldn't - for some reason now she's doing it perfectly

Comment: She may have just changed her mind or it took her some time to figure out how it works. They aren't the smartest little animals lol, they make up for it in cuteness though.

Answer (score 2):

- Give your hamster a few days to settle in. Hamsters can behave oddly on their first few days in a new place, it is new and scary for them.
- Make sure your cage is large enough for your hamster. They simply are not happy in small cages. It's area should be at least 360 inch<sup>2</sup> (around 2300 cm<sup>2</sup>) but more if possible. In a tiny cage, they will spend a lot of time simply trying to escape and pacing their cage in frustration. Also make sure it has a big enough wheel to run on because they have lots of energy

It sounds mostly like typical hamster behavior. It is probably exploring the cage and learning how everything works/how to get around in the tubes

Answer (score 1):

It could be she just changed her mind, or is stressed and is not sure how to get out since you said you only got her a few days ago.

Maybe let her out a little, waste her energy and when she's tired, put her back in. Just make sure the place has some covered hideouts if she'd like to hide, but set these hideouts in a way that you could get her right back when it's time to go back to cage. And, of course, she might want to climb something too.

It's all on you to make sure she doesn't get lost. And I'd suggest to get a hamster ball, that way she doesn't get lost and she could roam freely in your room. Hamster tubes with treats at the end of them can be very helpful too, as she could feel safe to be in a hideout and get treats when she comes out of it.

But hamster tubes should only be provided when the hamster feels safe around you, or else she might stay in the tube forever. To make the hamster feel less stressed and more safe, put her something in her cage so she could hide under. It's the first few days remember.

But also show her that you know where she is and still you won't hurt her. Touching her, petting her or giving her treats with your hand can make that happen.

Comment: Actually, hamsters - especially Syrians - _cannot_ live together. Syrians will fight each other and draw blood, and it quite possible for one Syrian to kill another one.

Comment: Ok then let her have fun with something else

Comment: No hamster balls... PLEASE! They are pure stress for hamsters!

Comment: Ok no hamster balls, Emil. For the sake of @Layna.

Comment: Hamster balls are not always bad - as long as its big enough, monitored closely, and the hamster goes in of their own decision. Some hamsters don't like it but for some its a safe way to explore outside their cage

Comment: I agree. It's just,as long as your hamster hates it or is afraid of it don't use it.